# mysql get minimum date, combine columns with group by

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table as follows: id, date and multiple `int` fields with 0/1. Only one `int` field in each row will contain a single 1 with the other columns all 0. Dates can be repeated for each `id`.

```
id     | date         | isX | isY | isZ
-------+--------------+-----+-----+-----
111111 | '1994-04-09' | 0   | 1   | 0
222222 | '1991-07-29' | 1   | 0   | 0
222222 | '1991-07-29' | 0   | 1   | 0
333333 | '1993-06-29' | 0   | 0   | 1
333333 | '1993-06-29' | 0   | 1   | 0
333333 | '1996-04-09' | 0   | 1   | 0
```

I want to get a single row for each `id`, with the earliest date and a 1 in each `int` column if any row with that `id` and date have a 1 (0 otherwise).

```
id     | date         | isX | isY | isZ
-------+--------------+-----+-----+-----
111111 | '1994-04-09' | 0   | 1   | 0
222222 | '1991-07-29' | 1   | 1   | 0
333333 | '1993-06-29' | 0   | 1   | 1
```

I was using the following command to combine the `int` columns

```
select id, 
    if(sum(isX)>0,1,0) as isX, 
    if(sum(isY)>0,1,0) as isY, 
    if(sum(isZ)>0,1,0) as isZ 
from table group by id;
```

but I wasn't sure how to use only those rows with the minimum date and how to add the date to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were there, just add `min(date)`

```
select id, 
    min(`date`) as mindate,
    if(sum(isX)>0,1,0) as isX, 
    if(sum(isY)>0,1,0) as isY, 
    if(sum(isZ)>0,1,0) as isZ 
from table 
group by id;
```

If you didn't want rows for each id where the rows `date` is not the id's min(date) then you'll need a subquery:

```
select id, 
    `date`
    if(sum(isX)>0,1,0) as isX, 
    if(sum(isY)>0,1,0) as isY, 
    if(sum(isZ)>0,1,0) as isZ 
from table 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id, min(date) as mindate FROM table GROUP BY id) sub1 ON
      table.id = sub1.id AND
      table.`date` = sub1.`date`
group by id, `date`;
```

Now the `if(sum(isx...` logic will only be used against records where the `date` is the `min(date)` for the `id`.